# PHP database Excel export

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a PHP script to export data from MySQL into Excel.
The first row of the Excel sheet is a column heading. I want them to appear in bold. How do I do this?
I am using the following code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","password");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect to DB: \n' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("ALNMSI", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM survey1");

$filename = "alnmsi_" . date('d-m-Y') . ".xls";

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); $flag = false;

$flag = false;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if(!$flag)
    {
        data_keys();
        $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
    data_array($row);
}
```

Comment: does Excel not format docs excessively like Word does?

Comment: i.e. Excel might not accept raw text.....

Comment: no excel does accept raw text, the excel file is being created properly now i want to introduce a bit of formatting in the excel file. i need the first row to be in bold

Comment: what library are you using to generate excel file?

Comment: i am not using a library, the headers i am using informs the browser that instead of the output being displayed on the web page it shgould be downloaded into and .xls file

Comment: Show us your `data_array()` function, since that is where you are having problems. If you are outputting some column formatted file or CSV data, then I'm afraid we cannot help making any text bold.

Comment: If you're not using a library, then the probability is that you're not actually generating an Excel file, just a text file (CSV probably, though the code you've posted doesn't show any file generation at all) with an extension of .xls. Simply setting headers is pretty meaningless. If I echoed text containing the dialogue from Star Wars and set the headings to pretend it was a .mov file, I wouldn't expect the "film" I'd created to be playable in Movie Player

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are doing it wrong. Whatever you output it's probably not a valid Excel file, since you didn't mention [BIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats) (this is the binary format which Excel files would be made of).

If you output TAB or COMMA separated values, then Excel only accidentially opens it correctly. And there is no way to style headers.

Also read:

- [PHP to Excel, bold font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457599)
- [MySQL to Excel generation using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713562)
- [Format text in Excel file via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279917)
- [Output Excel file in PHP after echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629945)

Answer (score 4):

You should use a library to generate Excel files.

- PHPExcel :
  http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/
- Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer :
  http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.intro.php

Comment: the pear excel writer appears to only work upto excel5.0 not 7.0.

Comment: also i dont want to introduce such completixity into my code so as to use PHPExcel classes. Is there no other way i can use the html bold and underline tags to do this ?

Comment: I think you will add more complexity trying to avoid such librairies. If you are building new files I do not see the problem. Excel 7 is able to open excel 5 files.